# Can user code create a new memory segment?

Tags: x86-64, memory-segmentation

I've been researching about memory segmentation, and it's been giving me lots of ideas for potential ways in which user code could benefit from swapping out segment registers. Specifically, I am interested in the x86-64 architecture because that's what I have.

Is there any way in which a user-mode program can create a new segment, for internal use?
To what extent can a program configure its own address space?

I imagine the GDT is way outside of a process' reach, but can a process modify the LDT?
Sorry if I sound naive, this is new stuff for me.

I also imagine that, if there even is a way to do this, it will almost certainly pass through OS specific functions. How would one do this in, say, Win32? I have found `GetThreadSelectorEntry` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getthreadselectorentry), but I haven't been able to find the equivalent `SetThreadSelectorEntry`.

Comment: You could do it on page-level: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/virtual-memory-functions

Comment: Some OSes have system calls like Linux's `modify_ldt`.  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/modify_ldt.2.html.

Comment: Whether or not you call that a "segment" is another matter; you have to have pages mapped for the part of linear address space that you want to use, whether you access it via a normal segment (base fixed at 0 in x86-64), or via FS or GS base.  (Which in x86-64 you'd normally set by asking the OS do to *that* directly, e.g. `arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS)` system call https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/arch_prctl.2.html, because the `wrfsbase` instruction isn't supported on all CPUs, and the OS has to enable user-space use of it.  The fallback mechanism is an MSR, not LDT)